# Allow checkout only on HEAD Revision TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am new to TortoiseSVN but I have a grasp on how version control software works.

For this scenario I am trying to block read/write access of older revisions of files I have in a repository and only allow read access to the HEAD revision.

Is it possible to configure a repository that a user can access a repository but only have access to one file?